# Using Tensorboard to graph from a log directory

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Can anyone give me a quick and dirty tutorial about how to modify the code in the [this MNIST tutorial](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/index.md/) and [this seq2seq tutorial](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/index.md) to log things to a log directory which can then be used in TensorBoard? I didn't really understand the ones on the official site.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a [SummaryWriter](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train.md#SummaryWriter) object, passing it the log directory, and call `add_summary` to log summaries and events to files in that directory. [word2vec.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/embedding/word2vec.py#L383) has an example. You can simply point TensorBoard at the log directory by passing it through `--logdir` and visualize the summaries.